# Two-Headed Arrow Over Formula

Tags: equations, graphics, arrows

I have a quantified formula. I want to show what happens when the order of quantifiers is reversed. To do this, I like to use a two-headed arrow over the formula, like this:

[image]

Is it possible? I don't care if you use graphical packages (like TikZ), as long as I can place the arrow in the right place.

Comment: Interesting!  This would also be useful for anyone using Bourbaki’s syntax for binders/quantifiers: to avoid using actual named variables and so having to deal with α-equivalence etc., he adds edges linking each binder to the occurrences of its bound ‘variables’; the edges are drawn much like your arrow but without the arrowheads, iirc.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for your interest. Off-topic: Can you provide a link for "Bourbaki’s syntax"?

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=IL-SI67hjI4C&lpg=PP1&dq=bourbaki%20set%20theory&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q&f=false (p. 15)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On way to do this with TikZ is the following:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
a
% `inner sep=0` removes unwanted padding in the nodes;
% `baseline, anchor=base` alignes the baseline of the text in the nodes 
%      with the baseline of the sourrounding text;
% `>=latex` selects the arrow style (see the TikZ manual for which
%      arrows are available.
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0cm,baseline,anchor=base,>=latex]
    % the first node, named 'left-node'
    \node (left-node) {$(\forall x \in X)$};

    % add a second node to the right of left-node
    \node [right=0cm of left-node] (right-node) {$(\forall y \in Y)$};

    % draw the connecting line between the north sides of the two nodes,
    % 1.5ex above the nodes.
    \draw[<->,red] (left-node.north) |- +(0,1.5ex) -| (right-node.north);

    % alternatively, draw a line between the north sides of the two nodes, with
    % starting angle 30° and ending at 150°.
    %\draw[<->,red] (left-node.north) to[out=30,in=150] (right-node.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
b
\end{document}
```

Which gives [image: example 1] or [image: example 2], depending on which of the lines starting with `\draw` you uncomment. Depending on where you want to use this, you might want to add `\displaystyle` in the math in the two nodes.

---

There seems to be interest in doing something like `pst-node` in TikZ. A first approximation would be (the following examples need to be compiled two times)

```
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=-1ex] \node (#1) {};}

\[(\forall x\tikzmark{a}\in X)(\forall y\tikzmark{b}\in Y)\]
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[<->,red] (a.north) |- +(0,1.5ex) -| (b.north);
```

This is however not quite what one wants, in this case, as the mark is not in the middle: [image: example]

Adding a second parameter to `\tikzmark` is not quite trivial as just putting the content into a node destroys all context (mathmode, spacing, etc.). I can't quite follow what `pst-node` does in `\rnode` (but judging from the result some space gets lost). If the usage is limited to simple cases, the following should work reasonably well (if necessary add `\displaystyle`):

```
\newcommand\tikzmark[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline,anchor=base] \node (#1) {$#2$};}

\[(\forall x\tikzmark{a}{\in} X)(\forall y\tikzmark{b}{\in} Y)\]
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[<->,red] (a.north) |- +(0,1.5ex) -| (b.north);
```

[image: example]

There is one more problem: overlayed pictures do not take any space, so the line and arrows might collide with text on the preceding line. I don't know how to fix this without manually adding some space.

---

With my first example, you can also do more fancy things, like

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0cm,baseline,anchor=base,>=latex,decoration=brace]
    \node (left-node) {$(\forall x \in X)$};
    \node [right=0cm of left-node] (right-node) {$(\forall y \in Y)$};

    \draw[decorate,red] ($(left-node.north west)+(0.3ex,0.2ex)$) -- ($(left-node.north east)+(-0.3ex,0.2ex)$);
    \draw[decorate,red] ($(right-node.north west)+(0.3ex,0.2ex)$) -- ($(right-node.north east)+(-0.3ex,0.2ex)$);
    \draw[<->,red,transform canvas={yshift=1.2ex}] (left-node.north) to[out=30,in=150] (right-node.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot. The comments help a lot. I liked the idea of arc instead of straight line.

Answer (score 7):

Usually I also prefer [pgf/tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf). Nevertheless here comes a quick solution with [pst-node](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
  \[
    (\forall x\rnode{a}{\in} X)(\forall y\rnode{b}{\in} Y)
  \]
  \ncbar[angle=90,arrows=<->,nodesep=2pt]{a}{b}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: I thought about doing something of this kind in TikZ, but then opted for automatic alignment of the arrow endpoints. But of course this is a lot more compact.

Comment: Furthermore it has the advantage that it can be used easily in common math environments. I tried »pgf/tikZ« with nodes and the `remember picture` option but couldn't make it work yet.

Comment: I tried the exact same thing, and had the same result.  I'd love to see a library like this for TikZ, because it definitely seems doable.  Does anybody know of one?

Comment: Thanks. I liked this solution for its compactness; but unfortunately `pst-node` does not work with `pdflatex`. In the environment I work, I can't compile to `PS` (because of using PDF-specific options).

Comment: @Antal See my edited answer.